# Permissions previously granted through install, will they automatically be granted when updating to new version compiled with SDK 23?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an app compiled with SDK version 22, so all my 'dangerous' permissions were granted on app install on all devices. When I redeploy with a version updated to SDK 23, will the devices with Android 6.0+ that had already granted the dangerous permissions through install still have these permissions granted, or will they have to be re-granted through the new model?

I ask because the app will attempt to use the permissions based on settings in SharedPreferences, outside of the flow I am using to individually grant the permissions for new installations. This will cause a crash on 6.0 devices if these permissions are not already granted.

Comment: "still have these permissions granted" -- I believe so. That being said... "the app will attempt to use the permissions based on settings in SharedPreferences, outside of the flow I am using to individually grant the permissions for new installations" -- that sounds like a really bad plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the app will be updated and automatically get the existing permissions. However, if in your update you declare the app has new permissions, those will not be granted.

Regardless, your API 23 version of the app will need to handle permissions properly by checking for them and requesting, as needed.